# Attempting to debug the terraform-provider-azurerm so that I can contribute to the community. But terraform plan crashes

Tags: go, debugging, terraform, azure-rm

### Introduction

Hi guys, I am trying to get started with contributing to the terraform-provider-azurerm. I have noticed a problem with the `azurerm_firewall_network_rule_collection`  I have reported it [here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/11181). I thought I should take this as an opportunity to see if I can chip in and try to fix the problem I have reported! If I can debug the provider and see how the code works, then not only will I learn go, I will also be able to figure out and help with bug fixes/feature enhancements. 
 Any Help you guys can provide me and guide me towards the right direction will be much appreciated. I know your time is precious, and I did my best before coming to ask for help.

Summary of what I have tried to do the folllowing:

- Fork the `terraform-provider-azurerm` repository.
- Clone the forked repo to my local. I am using `Ubuntu 20.04` in WSL.
- Running `vscode` version `1.54.3`
- using `terraform 0.14.9`, used `tfenv` to install and manage different versions.
- Install `golang` and related go tools in vscode. I am on `go version go1.16.2 linux/amd64`. Used `linuxbrew` to install go.
- Install `gcc5`. Used `linuxbrew` to install.
- Install `delve` debugger. Used `linuxbrew` to install.
- Create a very simple terraform `main.tf` which just deploys a resource group to my Azure subscription.
- Create a `.terraformrc` file ( set it in the location `/home/rahul/.terraformrc` ) to supply dev_overrides path to the provider.
- Modify the `main.go` ( location `/usr/local/go/src/github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/main.go`) to use debug statements.
- Compile the provider with the debug code and create new binaries.
- Attach dlv in headless mode to this binary
- Use the data from the previous step to set it in the variable TF_REATTACH_PROVIDERS
- Run Terraform plan - hoping that have a successful plan runs.
- Turn off debug mode and compile the provider and then run terraform plan.
- Plan runs successfully using the local provider.

### The Problem

- The plan crashes with

  ```
  Terraform crashed! This is always indicative of a bug within Terraform.
  A crash log has been placed at "crash.log" relative to your current
  working directory. It would be immensely helpful if you could please
  report the crash with Terraform[1] so that we can fix this.
  ```
- Content from log output

```
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [INFO] Terraform version: 0.14.9  
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [INFO] Go runtime version: go1.15.6
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [INFO] CLI args: []string{"/home/rahul/.tfenv/versions/0.14.9/terraform", "plan"}
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [DEBUG] Attempting to open CLI config file: /home/rahul/.terraformrc
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 Loading CLI configuration from /home/rahul/.terraformrc
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [DEBUG] Explicit provider installation configuration is set
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [TRACE] Selected provider installation method cliconfig.ProviderInstallationDirect with includes [] and     excludes []
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [INFO] CLI command args: []string{"plan"}
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [TRACE] Meta.Backend: built configuration for "local" backend with hash value 666019178
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [TRACE] Preserving existing state lineage "8773571c-7605-2553-b418-08cbb37374a4"
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [TRACE] Preserving existing state lineage "8773571c-7605-2553-b418-08cbb37374a4"
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [TRACE] Meta.Backend: working directory was previously initialized for "local" backend
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [TRACE] Meta.Backend: using already-initialized, unchanged "local" backend configuration
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [TRACE] Meta.Backend: instantiated backend of type *local.Local
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [TRACE] providercache.fillMetaCache: scanning directory .terraform/providers
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [TRACE] getproviders.SearchLocalDirectory: .terraform/providers is a symlink to .terraform/providers
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [TRACE] getproviders.SearchLocalDirectory: found registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v2.53.0 for    linux_amd64 at .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm/2.53.0/linux_amd64
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [TRACE] providercache.fillMetaCache: including .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/    azurerm/2.53.0/linux_amd64 as a candidate package for registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm 2.53.0
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [DEBUG] Provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm is overridden to load from /usr/local/go/bin
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in "."
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [DEBUG] checking for provisioner in "/home/rahul/.tfenv/versions/0.14.9"
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [INFO] Failed to read plugin lock file .terraform/plugins/linux_amd64/lock.json: open .terraform/   plugins/linux_amd64/lock.json: no such file or directory
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [TRACE] Meta.Backend: backend *local.Local supports operations
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [INFO] backend/local: starting Plan operation
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [TRACE] backend/local: requesting state manager for workspace "default"
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [TRACE] backend/local: state manager for workspace "default" will:
  - read initial snapshot from terraform.tfstate
  - write new snapshots to terraform.tfstate
  - create any backup at terraform.tfstate.backup
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [TRACE] backend/local: requesting state lock for workspace "default"
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: preparing to manage state snapshots at terraform.tfstate
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: no previously-stored snapshot exists
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: locking terraform.tfstate using fcntl flock
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: writing lock metadata to .terraform.tfstate.lock.info
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [TRACE] backend/local: reading remote state for workspace "default"
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: reading latest snapshot from terraform.tfstate
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: snapshot file has nil snapshot, but that's okay
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [TRACE] statemgr.Filesystem: read nil snapshot
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [TRACE] backend/local: retrieving local state snapshot for workspace "default"
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [TRACE] backend/local: building context for current working directory
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [TRACE] terraform.NewContext: starting
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [TRACE] terraform.NewContext: loading provider schemas
  2021/04/05 06:09:50 [TRACE] LoadSchemas: retrieving schema for provider type "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm"
  panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
  [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x18 pc=0x20f82d2]

  goroutine 52 [running]:
  github.com/hashicorp/terraform/plugin.(*GRPCProviderPlugin).Client(0xc00054ef60, 0xc00054e560, 0xc0003321e0,    0x7f73af739388, 0xc00094a180, 0x0, 0xc000817a6c)
      <autogenerated>:1 +0x32
  github.com/hashicorp/go-plugin.(*RPCClient).Dispense(0xc00073ce40, 0x289bfc5, 0x8, 0x0, 0x0, 0x29cd9d8, 0xc0003a6b30)
      /go/pkg/mod/github.com/hashicorp/go-plugin@v1.3.0/rpc_client.go:159 +0x254
  github.com/hashicorp/terraform/command.unmanagedProviderFactory.func1(0x24b0360, 0xc000575950, 0xc0003a6c08, 0xc00000b270)
      /home/circleci/project/project/command/meta_providers.go:448 +0x248
  github.com/hashicorp/terraform/terraform.(*basicComponentFactory).ResourceProvider(0xc00017d4b0, 0xc000578d8a, 0x7,     0xc000578d80, 0x9, 0x28bc2ba, 0x15, 0x2892906, 0x1, 0xc000578d8a, ...)
      /home/circleci/project/project/terraform/context_components.go:55 +0x351
  github.com/hashicorp/terraform/terraform.loadProviderSchemas.func1(0xc000578d8a, 0x7, 0xc000578d80, 0x9, 0x28bc2ba, 0x15)
      /home/circleci/project/project/terraform/schemas.go:103 +0x36e
  github.com/hashicorp/terraform/terraform.loadProviderSchemas(0xc000731ec0, 0xc0002c11e0, 0x0, 0x2ce93a0, 0xc00017d4b0,  0xc0000f2080, 0x3dcafe0, 0xc0000f2050)
      /home/circleci/project/project/terraform/schemas.go:174 +0x250
  github.com/hashicorp/terraform/terraform.LoadSchemas(0xc0002c11e0, 0x0, 0x2ce93a0, 0xc00017d4b0, 0x0, 0x2, 0x7f73afb6b400)
      /home/circleci/project/project/terraform/schemas.go:84 +0xc6
  github.com/hashicorp/terraform/terraform.NewContext(0xc0003a79d0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc00098b900, 0x1)
      /home/circleci/project/project/terraform/context.go:205 +0x2ea
  github.com/hashicorp/terraform/backend/local.(*Local).contextDirect(0xc00015ef70, 0xc0008e2700, 0xc0002c11e0, 0x0, 0x0,     0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc000731d10, 0xc000421120, ...)
      /home/circleci/project/project/backend/local/backend_local.go:178 +0x2ff
  github.com/hashicorp/terraform/backend/local.(*Local).context(0xc00015ef70, 0xc0008e2700, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
      /home/circleci/project/project/backend/local/backend_local.go:111 +0xf18
  github.com/hashicorp/terraform/backend/local.(*Local).opPlan(0xc00015ef70, 0x2ce83a0, 0xc00073cb40, 0x2ce83a0,  0xc00073cb80, 0xc0008e2700, 0xc00073cb00)
      /home/circleci/project/project/backend/local/backend_plan.go:70 +0x2cb
  github.com/hashicorp/terraform/backend/local.(*Local).Operation.func1(0xc00017d130, 0xc00017d140, 0xc00017d150,     0xc00015ef70, 0xc00017d120, 0x2ce83a0, 0xc00073cb40, 0x2ce83a0, 0xc00073cb80, 0xc0008e2700, ...)
      /home/circleci/project/project/backend/local/backend.go:340 +0xe8
  created by github.com/hashicorp/terraform/backend/local.(*Local).Operation
      /home/circleci/project/project/backend/local/backend.go:334 +0x36d
```

### Detailed steps including source code.

I have followed the steps documented in [Terraform Docs - Debugger based debugging](https://www.terraform.io/docs/extend/debugging.html#debugger-based-debugging)

- Go Installation path => `/usr/local/go`
- terraform-provider-azurerm cloned to => `/usr/local/go/src/github.com/terraform-providers`
- terraform-provider-azurerm source path => `/usr/local/go/src/github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm`
- Terraform main.tf source path => `~/Code/terraform`
- My terraform code

  ```
    locals {
    location      = "australiaeast"
    resourcegroup = "rg-azfw"
  }

  terraform {
    backend "local" {}
  }

  terraform {
    required_providers {
      azurerm = {
        source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
        version = "2.53.0"
      }
    }
  }

  provider "azurerm" {
    tenant_id                  = "xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx"
    skip_provider_registration = true
    features {}
  }

  resource "azurerm_resource_group" "resourcegroup" {
    name     = local.resourcegroup
    lo
  ```
- My .terraformrc

  ```
    provider_installation {

    # Use /home/developer/go/bin as an overridden package directory
    # for the hashicorp/azurerm provider. This disables the version and checksum
    # verifications for this provider and forces Terraform to look for the
    # azurerm provider plugin in the given directory.
    dev_overrides {
      "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm" = "/usr/local/go/bin"
    }

    # For all other providers, install them directly from their origin provider
    # registries as normal. If you omit this, Terraform will _only_ use
    # the dev_overrides block, and so no other providers will be available.
     direct {}
    }
  ```
- Modified the main.go file in `terraform-provider-azurerm` so that the provider binary can be launched in debugger mode. Now the main function looks like :

  ```golang
  func main() {
      // remove date and time stamp from log output as the plugin SDK already adds its own
      log.SetFlags(log.Flags() &^ (log.Ldate | log.Ltime))
      var debugMode bool

      flag.BoolVar(&debugMode, "debug", true, "set to true to run the provider with support for debuggers like delve")
      flag.Parse()

      opts := &plugin.ServeOpts{ProviderFunc: azurerm.Provider}

      if debugMode {
          // TODO: update this string with the full name of your provider as used in your configs
          err := plugin.Debug(context.Background(), "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm", opts)
          if err != nil {
              log.Fatal(err.Error())
          }
          return
      }

      plugin.Serve(opts)
      // plugin.Serve(&plugin.ServeOpts{
      //  ProviderFunc: azurerm.Provider,
      // })
  }
  ```
- The vscode debugger launch config looks like :

  ```json
      {
          // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
          // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
          // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
          "version": "0.2.0",
          "configurations": [
              {
                  "name": "Connect to server",
                  "type": "go",
                  "request": "attach",
                  "mode": "remote",
                  "remotePath": "${workspaceFolder}",
                  "port": 36283,
                  "host": "127.0.0.1",
                  "apiVersion": 1
              }
          ]
      }
  ```
- Ran `make build` to build the binaries. It copies the binary to `$GOPATH/bin/` location.
- Launching the delv headless debugger with the command `dlv exec --listen=127.0.0.1:36283 --api-version=1 --headless $GOPATH/bin/terraform-provider-azurerm -- --debug`

  - The `--listen=127.0.0.1:36283` is an additional parameter I googled and figured out - not mentioned in terraform docs. This helps me in not changing the ports for debugging everytime I am launching the debugger.
- That produces an output like :

  ```
    API server listening at: 127.0.0.1:36283
    {"@level":"debug","@message":"plugin address","@timestamp":"2021-04-05T06:08:38.863169+10:00","address":"/tmp/  plugin594405865","network":"unix"}
    Provider server started; to attach Terraform, set TF_REATTACH_PROVIDERS to the following:
    {"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm":{"Protocol":"netrpc","Pid":16362,"Test":true,"Addr":{"Network":"unix","String":"/    tmp/plugin594405865"}}}
  ```
- Set the `TF_REATTACH_PROVIDERS` value

  ```sh
      export TF_REATTACH_PROVIDERS='{"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm":{"Protocol":"netrpc","Pid":16362,"Test":true,"Addr":{"Network":"unix","String":"/tmp/plugin594405865"}}}'
  ```
- Run the `terraform plan` in the folder where the tf source code is there.. And all goes boom.